# How to use qtransmission bittorrent?

Tags: 13.10

I have installed this program but have no idea how to use it.
Please  give me a guideline.
Instead of a simbol it shows a ?.

Answer (score 0):

download the .torrent file of the torrent you wanna download
now go to that .torrent file and right click > open with(or properties > open with tab) click qtorrent

qtorrent opens asks for location to download, specify it > ok

thats it :) 
welcome to ubuntu